# Can I run my server with a browser instead of on Nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, browser, server

I have a server. I have a few JavaScript files that dictate how the server should behave, and I have Nodejs installed.

I run those js files on Nodejs, and voila! My server works. It accepts http requests and returns responses.

Now, a browser is also capable of executing js code. So, in theory, I could delete Nodejs, install Firefox in my server, and have Firefox execute the js files (modified to fit Firefox's dialect).

Then, I could have a server that runs on Firefox!

Is this possible? If not, why not?

Comment: a browser can't listen for incoming TCP connections

Comment: Why would you even want that? Browsers are made for the client side to browse the web, Node.js is made for server side code. They are very different.

Comment: Not possible. "_modified to fit Firefox's dialect_". The "dialect" here is actually the environment, server environment is totally different from browser environment.

Comment: @MarkBaijens to see if it's possible

Answer (score 0):

There are many reasons why this is not possible in general:

1. **No server-side networking capability**.  A browser does not have the ability to receive an incoming TCP connection to serve an HTTP request.
2. **Missing Node.js, and its entire platform.**  Although it is JavaScript in both Node.js and in a web browser (and may even be the V8 JavaScript engine in both cases if your the browser is Chrome) the browser is still a substantially different environment from Node.js.  It is likely that many libraries and operating system services upon which your server depends will be missing, like a file system for example.  Although it's possible to "browserify" certain node.js modules for use in the browser, in general, the kinds of things that a webserver does are significantly different from the things that a browser does in terms of its platform requirements.
3. **Lack of security**.  There's no good standard way of doing this safely.  Probably because of all the security risks in permitting browsers to host services and accept incoming connections without being properly configured as servers.  Although there may be extensions for specific browsers that provide some kind of functionality to accept an incoming connection, this is not standard web browser behaviour because it is fundamentally unsafe.  A local sandboxed browser wouldn't have access to system resources to perform server-like actions.

Your best bet is to use continue using Node.js as your web server.